# Ruby cannot load file required in test_helper

Tags: ruby

This is the file structure of my gem under Documents folder:

```
my_client
  lib
    my_client.rb
  test
    test_helper.rb
    test_my_client.rb
  my_client-1.0.0.gem 
  miracl_client.gemspec
  Rakefile
```

My `test_helper.rb` file looks like:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'my_client'
```

and I have `require 'test_helper'` line on top of my test_my_client.rb file.

Error message when I try to run tests by typing `ruby -I. test_miracl_client.rb`:

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- my_client (LoadError)
```

What's the right configuration of test_helper (and maybe Rakefile if that's necessary) to load my_client.rb where class MyClient is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
require_relative '../lib/my_client'
```

?